# Can I use PAN over Bluetooth to connect an accessory to an iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, bluetooth

I'm building an accessory that needs to send data to and from an iPad. I'm not interested in the advanced functionality that I get from the apple specific protocol, I just want to pass bits around. Is it possible to use PAN to accomplish this?

Comment: You mean like doing file transfer without the file transfer protocol?

Comment: Sure, I just want something to pass bits around.

Answer (score 1):

Apple only allows to use GameKit for iOS-to-iOS communication, or, to join the Made for iPhone program and actually build & certify your device (you can then use the ExternalAccessory Framework). That's it for AppStore conformity.

If Jailbreaking is an option, you may use BTstack.org (disclaimer: i'm the author) to connect to your accessory either using L2CAP or RFCOMM.